# Why my C++14 KosaRaju algo getting TLE when a similar written code runs much faster

Tags: c++, graph, c++14, kosaraju-algorithm

TLE code completes at 2.1 secs. I'm also passing many things through reference but it's still throwing a TLE. Why this code takes so much time?

here is the problem at hackerearth:

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/falling-dominos-49b1ed46/

Dominos are lots of fun. Children like to stand the tiles on their side in long lines. When one domino falls, it knocks down the next one, which knocks down the one after that, all the way down the line. However, sometimes a domino fails to knock the next one down. In that case, we have to knock it down by hand to get the dominos falling again. Your task is to determine, given the layout of some domino tiles, the minimum number of dominos that must be knocked down by hand in order for all of the dominos to fall.

Input

The first line of input contains one integer specifying the number of test cases to follow. Each test case begins with a line containing two integers, each no larger than 100 000. The first integer n is the number of domino tiles and the second integer m is the number of lines to follow in the test case. The domino tiles are numbered from 1 to n. Each of the following lines contains two integers x and y indicating that if domino number x falls, it will cause domino number y to fall as well.

Output

For each test case, output a line containing one integer, the minimum number of dominos that must be knocked over by hand in order for all the dominos to fall.

SAMPLE INPUT 
1
3 2
1 2
2 3
SAMPLE OUTPUT 
1

**code completes at 2.1**

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <unordered_set>
    #include <stack>

    using namespace std;


    void dfs(const vector<vector<int>> &edges, unordered_set<int> &visited,int sv, stack<int> &stk){
        visited.insert(sv);
        for(int i=0;i<edges[sv].size();i++){
            int current = edges[sv][i];
            if(visited.find(current)==visited.end())
                dfs(edges, visited, current, stk);
        }
        stk.push(sv);
    }

    void dfs(const vector<vector<int>> &edges, unordered_set<int> &visited,int sv){
        visited.insert(sv);
        for(int i=0;i<edges[sv].size();i++){
            int current = edges[sv][i];
            if(visited.find(current)==visited.end())
                dfs(edges, visited, current);
        }
    }


    int main()
    {
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
            int V, E;
            cin>>V>>E;
            vector<vector<int>> edges(V+1);
            unordered_set<int> visited;
            stack<int> stk;
            while(E--){
                int f, s;
                cin>>f>>s;
                edges[f].push_back(s);
            }

            for(int i=1;i<=V;i++)
                if(visited.find(i)==visited.end())
                    dfs(edges, visited, i, stk);

            visited.clear();
            int count{0};
            while(!stk.empty()){
                int current = stk.top();
                stk.pop();
                if(visited.find(current)==visited.end()){
                dfs(edges, visited, current);
                count++;
                }
            }
           cout<<count<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**Efficient Code completes at 0.7 sec.**

```
  #include<iostream>

    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

       void dfs( vector<int> *edges , int start,int n,bool *visit ,stack<int> *nodex)
        {

          visit[start]  = true;
    //       cout<<start<<endl;

          for (int i = 0; i < edges[start].size(); ++i)
          {
                int next = edges[start][i];

                  if(visit[next] == false)
                   dfs(edges,next,n,visit,nodex);

          }

             nodex->push(start);
        }

     void dfs(vector<int> *edges,int start, bool *visit,int n)
    {
        visit[start] = true;

        for(int i=0;i<edges[start].size();i++)
        {
        int next = edges[start][i]; 
            if(visit[next]==false)
            dfs(edges,next,visit,n);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int t;
        cin>>t;
      while(t--)
    {
           int n,m;
           cin>>n>>m;

           vector<int> *edges = new vector<int>[n+1];

                for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
                {
                    int start,end;
                     cin>>start>>end;

                     edges[start].push_back(end);  
                }

                //  cout<<"PHASE 1"<<endl;

                  bool *visit = new bool[n+1];

                  for (int i = 0; i<=n; ++i)
                  {
                    visit[i] = false;
                  }


                stack<int> *nodex = new stack<int>();

                 for (int i = 1; i<=n; ++i)
                   {
                     if(visit[i]  == false)
                       dfs(edges,i,n,visit,nodex);
                   }
                //   cout<<"PHASE 2"<<endl;

             for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
              visit[i] = false;

                   int count=0;
                   while(!nodex->empty())
                        {
                       int up = nodex->top();
                        nodex->pop();
    //                  cout<<" EVERYTHING ISS FINE  "<<up<<endl;
                            if(visit[up] ==false )
                            {
                                dfs(edges,up,visit,n);
                                count++;
                            }       
                    //        cout<<"Everrything is fine "<<up<<endl;

                        }
                        cout<<count<<endl;

    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try to get rid of `unordered_set`, it might be too slow, better use array of bools as in the second code

Comment: 1) Put the sample input into the code -- there is no need for `cin` statements.  2) `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- use the proper header files, not this one.

Comment: It's literally as simple as examining the two pieces of code and noting differences (without letting hubris dismiss your differences as not meaningful).

Comment: For those not familiar with abbreviations, TLE == Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: @fas I removed the `unordered_set` it started working now. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added the problem link so that anyone can paste the code at problem platform and in could be used. Also proper header files are used in my solution.

Comment: @sweenish its not simple. later I altered the code and realized the use of hashing was not efficient here. and the first code is mine and the second code is my friends'

Comment: @HarshSahu -- *I have added the problem link so that anyone can paste the code at problem platform* -- An outside platform is meaningless.  What is desirable is for you to come up with the test case, and then anyone can take the code, compile it, and run it *on their local compiler*.  No one is going to spend time on tweaking stuff with an online website's compiler.  The way you figure these problems out is to have the programs running locally, where you have full control over the environment, compiler settings, etc.  and also get **real** timings, not what a website thinks is correct.

Comment: As to the second code, it has memory leaks all over the place due to the lack of `delete[]` -- it is not good code.  So you are comparing faulty code, and saying that it runs faster.  The lack of `delete[]` calls could easily add more time to the execution of the code you see.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your suggestion. I'll make sure to make code run locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Fast I/O and "\n"in place of endl. This helps a lot in getting rid of TLE. For me the rest of the code seems to be fine

Comment: agree but dont think it matters a lot in case of above question